# braket package not working

Tags: math-mode

I am new to overleaf and latex syntax, and I am having trouble using Dirac's notation. I know it is pretty straightforward: `\usepackage{braket}` and then `\ket{\psi}` but it simply does not work. Am I missing something? Like the `\documentclass` or something? I am currently using `article`.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you forgot to use a [math environment](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_expressions).

```
% Tested on overleaf
\documentclass{article}
% https://ctan.org/pkg/braket
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

Inline $\ket{abc}$ math example.

\begin{equation}
\ket{abc}  
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: strong text]

PS: Friendly advice, next time please provide a clearer question that includes/features a so-called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). You also might want to have a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11).